# Does the closure of a set of positive Lebesgue measure contain an open set?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $L^n(A)$ denote the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure of a set $A \subset \mathbb R^n$. Suppose that $L^n(A)>0$. Is it true that the closure of $A$ contains an open set?

Comment: No, any fat Cantor set provides a counterexample. I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I will wait for someone with more experience in the measure-theory tag to judge which one is best.

Answer (score 4):

This is not true. Consider the fat Cantor set (see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith–Volterra–Cantor_set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set)). It is closed and has positive Lebesgue measure but contains no intervals. Thus, it cannot contain an open set since every open set contains an interval.